# How to read a cookie value from an Akka HTTP request

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm new to Akka HTTP and I want to know how to pull a cookie from an Akka HTTP request. If possible, can someone post an example of how this can be done using Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.11/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/cookie-directives/cookie.html) states, you can use the `cookie` directive to extract a cookie from a request:

> ```
> val route =
>   cookie("userName") { nameCookie =>
>     complete(s"The logged in user is '${nameCookie.value}'")
>   }
>
> // tests:
> Get("/") ~> Cookie("userName" -> "paul") ~> route ~> check {
>   responseAs[String] shouldEqual "The logged in user is 'paul'"
> }
> // missing cookie
> Get("/") ~> route ~> check {
>   rejection shouldEqual MissingCookieRejection("userName")
> }
> Get("/") ~> Route.seal(route) ~> check {
>   responseAs[String] shouldEqual "Request is missing required cookie 'userName'"
> }
> ```

There is also an [`optionalCookie`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.11/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/cookie-directives/optionalCookie.html) directive:

> ```
> val route =
>   optionalCookie("userName") {
>     case Some(nameCookie) => complete(s"The logged in user is '${nameCookie.value}'")
>     case None             => complete("No user logged in")
>   }
>
> // tests:
> Get("/") ~> Cookie("userName" -> "paul") ~> route ~> check {
>   responseAs[String] shouldEqual "The logged in user is 'paul'"
> }
> Get("/") ~> route ~> check {
>   responseAs[String] shouldEqual "No user logged in"
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I need to get more familiar with the framework before I could clearly understand the documentation.  It actually did help me to spend some time in other examples provided in the documentation.